# TO_DAYS() is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I require no of days after subtracting two dates without using `DATEDIFF` function in SQL Server. Using `TO_DAYS` gives error "TO_DAYS' is not a recognized built-in function name."

```
TO_DAYS(CAST(maxDeliveryDateTime as date) - TO_DAYS(CAST(maxOrderDateTime as date)
```

Comment: What is wrong with `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: It is available from MySQL 4.0. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_to_days.asp

Comment: `TO_DAYS` does not exist in SQL Server.

Comment: @SalmanA, our local environment is using HSQL .DATEDIFF function in HSQL requires " 'day' " to be in single quotes like DATEDIFF(('day','2019-12-10','2019-12-10') as DAYDIFF). However SQL Servers give error "Invalid parameter 1 specified for DATEDIFF". I need something which works in both DB

Comment: Every RDBMS uses a different flavour (dialect) of SQL, @Geek . You cannot expect SQL written for one RDBMS to work flawlessly on another. SQL needs to be written bespoke to the RDBMS you are using, in the native dialect. Even ANSI SQL will not work on every RDBMS, as none of them entirely support ANSI SQL, and what each one supports is not the same.

Comment: If you're using HSQL, why is the posting flagged with sql-server?

Comment: What alternative i can use instead which works in both rdms to subtract two dates.

Comment: @robbpriestley, HSQL is being used in local environment and SQLServer is in production environment. Thats why i tagged both

Comment: *"What alternative i can use instead which works in both rdms to subtract two dates."* Like I said, you have to write SQL specific to the RDBMS you are using at the time.

Comment: Don't test and develop on a different DBMS than you use in production. That is a recipe for loads of problems.

Comment: @Geek why are you using 2 different RDBMS for development and Production environments?! That's like writing code in VB.net in development and pushing the code to an asp.net Core (which is C#) application and asking "Why is my code not working?" It's not working because it's *wrong* language...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, for development we use HQL , but storefront is on SQLServer, that was project requirement . COuld you please suggest any things which can give me no of days between two dates other than DateDiff

Comment: *"that was project requirement ."* Then you're project is completely flawed. Change your development environment or the production to the same as the other. That is the solution here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is the OP is trying to deploy SQL written in one dialect to an instance which uses a different dialect. The problem is not the code but the OP's decision to deploy SQL in the wrong language to the instance. There is no programming based question here, the problem is purely based on deploying code in the wrong language for an environment. The OP needs to write in the correct dialect for the correct environment.

Comment: @Larnu, there is an alternative provided for Datediff to work in HQL . Please have a look here [forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=47775] . Is there any possibility of casting or converting two dates to get the differnece in sqlServer?

Comment: The way to get the difference in time between 2 dates, in **SQL Server** is to use `DATEDIFF`, @Geek . For days, that would be `DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate)`. if it were months it would be `DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, EndDAte)`. That code can/will be different in HSQL because they are *different* dialects. Write code for the environment you are using. Don't write HSQL code, and then deploy it to a SQL Server instance; it will *not* work.

Comment: I think your best bet is to program your own `TO_DAYS` function in SQL Server

Comment: You can get Sql Server Express Edition for free, IIRC Developer Edition is only $50. You should be using one of those locally if you production demands Sql Server. Trying to do developement on a different platform than production is **INSANE**.

Comment: Seems developer edition is now free, too: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/

Comment: Has been since 2014, iirc, @JoelCoehoorn . Might have been 2016. Been quite a few years either way.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot expect a script written to run on MSSQL to run on HSQL, and vice versa. They use different dialects of SQL. You may be able to find quite a bit of equivalency between the two sets of SQL statements, but you'll essentially need to have two separate versions of the script.

Comment: there is an alternative provided for Datediff to work in HQL . Please have a look here [https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=47775] .  Is there any possibility of casting or converting two dates to get the differnece in sqlServer?

Comment: I feel like by trying to force this that you are entering into a world of difficulty and trouble.